# How to bring column data to rows horizontally?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a dataset like this:

```
Number                 Job Title                Date
001                  Data analyst            01.01.2018
001                  Senior Data Analyst     01.01.2019
001                  Data Manager            01.01.2020
002                  Associate               01.01.2018
002                  Senior Associate        01.01.2020
```

I want it to be like this:

```
Number   Job Title1     Date1         Job Title2            Date2       Job Title3     Date3
001      Data analyst   01.01.2018    Senior Data Analyst   01.01.2019  Data Manager   01.01.2020                
002      Associate      01.01.2018     Senior Associate     01.01.2020
```

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Comment: What is your version of MySql?

Comment: I am using Bigquery basically. I could understand whatever you write in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Consider below approach

```
select *
from (
  select *, row_number() over(partition by number order by Date) pos
  from `project.dataset.table`
)
pivot (max(Job_Title) Job_Title, max(Date) Date for pos in (1, 2, 3, 4))
```

If applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Below version of above - allows you to not know in advance of how many columns to allocate and rather builds everything dynamically

```
execute immediate (             
select '''
  select * from (
    select *, row_number() over(partition by number order by Date) pos 
    from `project.dataset.table`
  )
  pivot(max(Job_Title) Job_Title, max(Date) Date for pos in (''' ||  string_agg('' || pos, ', ')  || '''))
'''
from (select pos
  from (select count(1) cnt from `project.dataset.table` group by Number order by cnt desc limit 1),
  unnest(generate_array(1, cnt)) pos 
) 
);
```

If apply this version to sample data in your question n- output is

[image]